# Joomla 1.5 memory issue on new server

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, windows-server-2012

I need to move a Joomla 1.5 site from my unix machine to a Windows 2012 host on request from my customer. Both servers are running PHP 5.3.26.

On my unix server, I can see that the site is using approx 40 MB RAM. The memory_limit is 128 MB.
When moving it to the Windows host, I get the following, rather famous, error message:

*Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 419430400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in E:\HostingSpaces\xxx\site.com\wwwroot\libraries\joomla\error\exception.php on line 117*

On the Windows host the memory limit is set to 400M.

Does anyone have an idea on what the problem could be here?

Comment: You have a memory leak somewhere (probably a stuck loop). Those 40 bytes represent the LAST 40 bytes it was trying to allocate which it could not fit into the memory limit (so it's not the total amount it's trying to allocate). We can't help you much if you don't give exact details as to how/where you got this error

Comment: The error gets thrown on index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the cause of an extension which is not correctly built and doesn't support Windows Server. You can try going into the SQL back-end and disabling all non vital extensions to see if that fixes the problem.

You are most probably stuck in a loop which causes a memory leak.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Is it enough just to change the published value in the plugins table?

Comment: yes that should be fine. Also check the modules, not only plugins. Maybe even setting default template to joomla's built in default template. You want to get the installation as close as possible to initial install

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good fix, and most likely wont be recommended. But you could do a fresh install of Joomla 1.5 on the Windows Server. Then manually install or add the Joomla Theme followed by replacing the MySQL DB from fresh install with the one from the old install. Once you have moved the old mysql db to the new installation all content should be there. Then you will need to add the extensions as well

It is probably worth mentioning that you should probably do a big upgrade to Joomla 3.x I believe they are up to now. If your concerned about losing content you can always save time with the old mysql db and adding that to the new joomla installation. If your using a joomla theme that you didn't build and you like the theme you may have a difficult time applying it to the new joomla if you built the theme you wont have an issue at all

Comment: Their problem is that they didn't build the theme. They've tried upgrading it to 2.5, and it was a mess. They haven't invested more time into a upgrade yet. But it's definitely a good idea, just doesn't solve this concrete problem that we need fixed asap.